# 3d visualization of vector data in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, data-visualization, vector-graphics

I am trying to visualize my data in 3D and different magnitude of vector with different color.

So far I have imported the data using, 'data = Import["File"]'
and used, 'vecdata = Partition[#, 3] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[data]'

The image should look close to this
[Vector map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eFQ5.jpg)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PUWVkJ4t3vC1KK8n4NWIjxIbQhl6JWRbeewPMjw9OFg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `ListVectorPlot3D` can do that.  How to put your data in the appropriate form for `ListVectorPlot3D` depends on the format of your source data.

Comment: By using "ListVectorPlot3D[vecdata]," I get an empty cube .        So, I imported each column individually from my file such as "x1 = import [File, {"Data",All,5}]" and then used "LIstVectorPlot3D[{{x1,y1,z1},{vx1,vy1,vz1}}]" and I get "is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets"

Answer (score 2):

So `ListVectorPlot3D` wants an array of vectors.  What you have is a list of ${x_i, y_i, z_i, Vx_i, Vy_i, Vz_i}$ elements.  If you had your x, y, and z points all laid out on a regular grid, then you could rearrange the elements to be in the correct format, but your data is not on a regular grid.  To get around this, I will create a linear interpolation function and use `VectorPlot3D`.  Also, your data has some duplicate points so I had to remove them.

I downloaded your data as a CSV file,

```
data = DeleteDuplicates@
   Import["~/Downloads/Cell Well data - Sheet1.csv"][[2 ;;]];

xfunc = Interpolation[(data[[All, ;; 4]]), InterpolationOrder -> 1];
yfunc = Interpolation[(data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 5}]]), 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
zfunc = Interpolation[(data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 6}]]), 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}} = 
  MinMax /@ Transpose[data][[;; 3]];

VectorPlot3D[{xfunc[x, y, z], yfunc[x, y, z], zfunc[x, y, z]}, {x, 
   xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, {z, zmin, zmax}] // Quiet
```

[image]